# Three length 3 "gapped" straights vs. one length 6 straight. Which is more likely and by how much?

Tags: probability, card-games

Using  a well shuffled standard $52$ card deck, $2$ players (call them A and B) decide to play a game.  They draw community (shared) cards (without replacement) until a winner for that hand is declared or they run out of cards to draw, whichever comes first.  For A to win, there has to be three length $3$ ascending straights drawn in order such as $6,7,8$ ... $2,3,4$... $10,J,Q$.  The $3$ straights have to all be "gapped" by at least $1$ rank so something like $7,8,9$ ... $10,J,Q$ ... $2,3,4$ is not a winner for A because of the $9$ and $10$ not being gapped.  The rank $2$ card is considered the lowest card and the $A$ card is considered the highest ranked card so $A,2,3$ is NOT considered a straight.  For B to win, there has to be a straight of length $6$ such as $7,8,9,10,J,Q$.

So who has the higher probability to win and by how much?

My initial simulation had an error in it so I fixed and am rerunning it.

An example of a tie would be  $2,3,4,6,7,8,7,8,9,10,J,Q$  The Q gives A and B the last card needed at the same time so that is a tie (no win for either).

I am now trying to do some mathematical analysis on paper starting with simple enumeration of the different ways for A to win.  I see $10$ patterns:

$~1$) $2,3,4,6,7,8,10,J,Q$
$~2$) $2,3,4,6,7,8,J,Q,K$
$~3$) $2,3,4,6,7,8,Q,K,A$
$~4$) $2,3,4,7,8,9,J,Q,K$
$~5$) $2,3,4,7,8,9,Q,K,A$
$~6$) $2,3,4,8,9,10,Q,K,A$
$~7$) $3,4,5,7,8,9,J,Q,K$
$~8$) $3,4,5,7,8,9,Q,K,A$
$~9$) $3,4,5,8,9,10,Q,K,A$
$10$) $4,5,6,8,9,10,Q,K,A$

For player B to win, there are only $8$ ways:

$1)~ 2,3,4,5,6,7$
$2)~ 3,4,5,6,7,8$
$3)~ 4,5,6,7,8,9$
$4)~ 5,6,7,8,9,10$
$5)~ 6,7,8,9,10,J$
$6)~ 7,8,9,10,J,Q$
$7)~ 8,9,10,J,Q,K$
$8)~ 9,10,J,Q,K,A$

What I will do is create a bucket for each possible  pattern (way) to win shown above and count them up to make sure the program is catching all of them.  I think they should all be equally likely.

What if we started by just doing a "straight" analysis of the probability or A winning ignoring any cases where B wins first?  What if we also do the same thing and compute the chances of B winning ignoring cases where A wins first.  I wonder how far off those will be from the simulated results.

Would this analysis be correct for computing the chance of B winning if there was no player A?

Chance of choosing good 1st card is $32/52$, good 2nd card is $4/51$, good 3rd card is $4/50$, good 4th card is $4/49$, good 5th card is $4/48$, and good 6th card is $4/47$.  This is about $1$ in $447,000$ but that is only counting an immediate win for B with only $6$ cards drawn.  B can use the full deck if need be to win so how do I compute that using math?  In other words, if the only player is B how many hands on average will be required for a B win?

Comment: Well, I have to guess A is more likely to win (disregard draws ofcourse). consider case in the middle of the game when a length 3 straight is just drawn, than the chance it will become to straight of length 4 is pretty low so we have already 1 straight of length of 3...so player B can't win and will pray for draw.

Comment: that's right, but the chance those number will be drawn are very low. if we have $7,8,9,5$ than it;s game over for player $B$, only $A$ can win from here.

Comment: that's right, but again...$A$ clearly has advantage here. for the simple fact the chance to have straight of 5 after having straight of 3 is lower than 50%. (pivot rule only makes it better for player $A$). please refer to Joffan answer.

Comment: my guess $A$ will have ~$20$ times more wins than $B$ in the long run. but most of games will finish without winner.

Comment: interesting. so do you have results so far ? (if you include draw ? )

Comment: Please delete any old comments because the original rules of this problem were too difficult to simulate so I greatly simplified the problem so these comments are not applicable anymore.  Also does anyone know how to increase an active bounty?  If so, how?

Comment: It might be helpful to generalize, then analyze/simulate much smaller similar problems. Imagine smaller decks (with fewer denominations) and runs of different lengths.

Comment: Are you saying this to help me solve it myself mathematically or cuz the math is proving to be too difficult to yourself?  I am not sure how lessening the number of denominations and # of cards makes the computation easier.  For example, $2$ gapped straights of length $2$ vs. a single straight of length $3$ in a $26$ card deck (taken from $52$ card deck).  That is a similar problem but seems equally difficult for me to get started on analytically (but should be MUCH faster to simulate on a computer).

Comment: @David I suggested that because it's often helpful in this kind of problem. You can analyze really small cases completely and may see patterns or ideas that generalize. Think about two gapped straights of length 2 vs a single straight of length 3 in a deck with $S$ suits, $k$ cards per suit. Start with $S=1$, $k=5, 6, \ldots$.. Note: I haven't tried this. It may not help. I suggest it because it's how I'd go about trying to understand the structure of the problem.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker - thanks I can try but my math skills are not so good.  is the difficulty of this problem because of $2$ players competing or because on average they need to draw more than half of the deck to get a winner?  Also, does the fact there winners are rare make this harder to solve as well?  How would you rate this problem on a scale of $1$ to $10$ as far as difficulty to solve mathematically? (10 = hardest).  The simulation is not that hard I just made a dumb error that I fixed.  I think predicting the probability of a tie would be difficult for this problem without using simulation.

Comment: I was hoping someone would help me to get started with this analysis.  So far I cannot even figure out how to determine the chances of either A or B winning solo.  I think I know the chances of B winning if only $6$ cards are drawn/checked.  I suppose a brute force method would be to assume all $52$ cards will be drawn.  B actually does win sometimes on the very last card.  I'll add code my simulation program to have a bucket for each possible # of cards dealt and see where most of B's wins are happening but it could happen anywhere between $6$ and $52$ cards inclusive.  I'll post soon.

Comment: Ok I ran $10~million$ hands only looking for B wins and the $47$ buckets seemed to fill up rather uniformly from $6$ to $52$ cards inclusive.  I don't see any major spikes or dips.  Next I will retry same # of hands but also look for A wins to see what happens to the buckets.  This means that if we just compute the probability of getting a solo B win  using only $6$ cards, that we can simply multiply that by $47$ (one for each bucket) and get a reasonable approximation of how often B should win solo dealing out the entire deck.  Should be about $47/447000$

Comment: $47/447000$ (about $1$ in $9500$) is actually quite a good approximation of the expected frequency of B wins either solo or against A.  Since wins for either are so infrequent, the chances of either one altering the outcome of  a solo round for any given hand is very small (almost negligible).  I computed the $447000$ myself just using simple math and the $47$ I got from the simulation program just observing that all the $47$ buckets have about the same value in them.  So this is a partial success for me although I somewhat cheated.  A pure mathematical solution is still quite elusive for me.

Comment: It seems somewhat reasonable to expect a $6$ card straight anywhere from card $6$ to $52$ as almost equally likely.  That is cuz even though the number of good cards is reduced as cards are drawn, so too are the number of bad cards that could mess up the straight.  It is quite conceivable that the straight can appear anywhere, even the last $6$ cards drawn.  I am checking the buckets from $10~million$ hands now to help re-confirm this.

Comment: Yes confirmed with $20~million$ hands, each bucket from $6$ to $52$ cards drawn has about the same number of B winners with a few exceptions. Low is $22$ winners and high is $60$ winners so I don't know if that is normal to have close to a $3:1$ ratio between high and low can someone tell me please? The average seems to be low $40$s I think I might see a slight bias towards the $6$ to $9$ card range being higher than average and the $49$ to $52$ range being lower than average but it could be a "fluke" for this run. I'll run for much longer and fill those buckets up a lot more and see..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems A has the advantage, not B like I originally thought.  I put extra checks into the program to make sure it is working correctly.  I originally missed a few cases for A winning, thus the program reported lower winnings for A than should have been.  Simulating $250~million$ hands, I am now seeing $38,060$ wins for A and $24,337$ wins for B with $4$ ties.  So that is about $61$% for A and about $39$% for B when someone wins the hand.  Average # of cards for each win was about $41.2$ for A and about $28.8$ for B for a weighted average of about $36.4$.  That is, if any win happens, either A or B, on average about $36.4$ cards will have been drawn which is more than $2/3$rds of the entire deck.  For the $4$ ties, average # of cards was $(43+45+51+29)/4 = 42$.

The $29$ card tie had the following cards (T=$10$):

3Q$345$K$89T$A932Q7AQ89847J$9TJQKA$

In this run of $250~million$ hands, the shortest card sequence for a win for A was $9$ and for B was $6$.  The longest card sequence for both was $52$ (for a win).

Another interesting thing I tried was I programmed the simulation to tell me how often in all $52$ cards will A and B both have a candidate win (but not necessarily on the same card).  Out of $10~million$ full $52$ card hands, it reported on $8$ were multicandidate winners.  That helps explain why ties are even more rare cuz for those you need $2$ candidate winners AND they both must be on the same final drawn card (such as card $42$ for example).

The only thing slightly suspicious I see with the revised (corrected) code is I made buckets for each of the $10$ ways (patterns) where A can win and also the $8$ ways (patterns) where B can win thinking they would all be about the same number but there seems to be a slight bias towards the lowest numbered bucket for each, indicating that the low # card wins are appearing more.  This may be cuz of the way I check for wins which starts at the lowest numbered sequences (such as $2,3,4$) and whenever A or B wins, the checking is "short circuited" (terminated) for that hand.  It could also be that $250~million$ hands is not enough to allow them (the buckets) to "normalize".  Perhaps I need $1~billion$ or more hands.

My simulation works by first shuffling the entire deck of $52$ cards and then I simply search the entire deck for the $18$ patterns ($10$ for A and $8$ for B) that indicate a candidate win for either.  I also check for ties. Sometimes A and B have candidate wins in the same hand but one comes before the other.  In that case I simply award the win to whoever got the candidate win first (with the fewer number of cards).  It seemed simpler to me to implement the simulation this way since I don't have to pick one card at a time and check for a winner as I go.  It is like I shuffle the deck, lay all the cards out on a table all at once, then search for the winner.  Even using an interpreted language (not compiled) which only uses $50$% of my CPU max and is much slower than any compiled language, I can simulate $1$ million hands in about $1.3$ minutes.  $1$ billion would take about $22$ hours. Someday I would like to implement this in c or some other compiled language and see how fast I can get it to go.

It is fun having a simulation program for card games like this cuz it allows easy analysis of different patterns by just making buckets for them to just count up.

If this problem is too difficult to solve mathematically, I wish someone else would at least try a simulation as well to confirm the results and compare speeds.

Comment: Consider all 52! ways to deal out 52 cards and count the number of deals in which pattern 2 occurs. Now count how often pattern 1 occurs. The number of matching deals should be the same in each case. But in some of the deals that match pattern 2, the first J,Q,K will be preceded by a 10, and those deals will count only for pattern 1 when you play the game. So you should expect to see pattern 1 wins more often than pattern 2 no matter how many hands you simulate.

Comment: @David K - Yes that is what I am seeing.  Bucket 1 which is pattern 1 for an A win had $4437$ wins but the other $9$ buckets hovered around $3800$.  I don't see why if the first $6$ cards drawn are $2,3,4,6,7,8$ that bucket $1$ should then fill quicker than bucket $2$ cuz at that point, $10,J,Q$ and $J,Q,K$, and $Q,K,A$ sequences are equally likely.  There would be $4$ each of those high ranked cards remaining in the deck.

Comment: @David K - I am seeing the same relationship with bucket $4$ being greater than bucket $5$ and bucket  $7$ being greater than bucket $8$, both by very roughly $10$%.  However, bucket $1$ seems to be out in front of the "pack" by more than $15$% on average.  Okay I think I understand your explanation now about all $52!$ hands and how a $10$ could "sneak" in there, taking a potential bucket $2$ win and placing it in bucket $1$ instead.

Comment: F.Y.I., using the 2 tuples of (bucket number = pattern, # of wins) the number of wins per bucket for A were ($1, 4437$),($2, 3802 $), ($3, 3799$), ($4, 3845$), ($5, 3587$), ($6, 3830$), ($7, 3936$), ($8, 3466$), ($9, 3632$), ($10, 3891$).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is clearly player $A$. Once the first run of three appears, $B$ can only win if the run continues (assuming it can), but $A$ can win from every subsequent card based on one or usually two possible directions for the run. This is true even without your addition of pivot cards, which make the odds even better for $A$, since then $A$ can win in an entirely symmetric way to $B$ from the end of the first run of three.

Comment: Well, I don't think the pivot rule makes in entirely symmetric, because after drawing $5,6,7$ it's more likely to draw $8,9$ than $6,5$.

Comment: @David that might be closer, true.

Comment: @d_e not completely symmetric, but the run continuation is not guaranteed to be viable either.

Comment: Once the first run of three appears, $B$ can still win even if that first run ends before the fifth card. For example, $4,5,6,K,7,6,5,4,3$ is a win for $B$ due to the requirement that $A$'s two straights must be "gapped". I would guess the game still favors $A$, however.

Comment: I understand your added condition, but it is slightly at odds with the pivot concept.

Comment: This answer was given when the problem was different (much harder) so it doesn't apply to the revised simpler problem.  After the original rules, I realized it was a nightmare to simulate so I greatly simplified it to make it amenable to both simulation and hopefully mathematical analysis too.